# React Native App Authentication with Instagram API

Tags: react-native, instagram-api

I've been trying to build a react native app that requires users to authenticate with their Instagram account. The Instagram API has a authorisation link and perhaps the only way to display that in an app would be through 'WebView' and so I used that.

The authentication workflow runs smoothly and then my server even gets the access token and user-id. But the problem is how to send this access token back to the app? I've used express-js for the 'redirect-uri' and so the WebView makes request to app.get() handler. In order to send response to same client on which the connection is opened, we must use res.send(). This would send the response to WebView, let's say I capture that using 'injectedJavaScript' but this javascript runs within WebView and so its unable to access react-native variables. In the event of a correct access-token, how would I ever navigate away from the WebView?

Any solutions to the above problems would be greatly appreciated. I suspect that there might even be problems with this approach(in my choice of WebView for this purpose, etc.), so a change of approach even entirely would also be of help. All I want is to authenticate the app users with Instagram and get my project going. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Expo, you can use AuthSessions to accomplish this (https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/auth-session). The exact way to do it depends on whether you are using a managed workflow or a bare workflow, etc., but for managed workflow you can do the following:

1. Go to the Facebook Developer's console, go to your app, and add the Instagram Basic Display product.
2. Under Instagram Basic Display, under Valid OAuth Redirect URIs, use `https://auth.expo.io/@your-expo-username/your-project-slug` (project slug is in your `app.json` file)
3. On the same FB Developer page, add an Instagram tester profile and then follow the steps to authenticate that user.
4. In your project, install `expo install expo-auth-session` and import it into your Component
5. Also install `expo-web-browser`
6. Code your component like so:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Button, Platform, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import { useAuthRequest, makeRedirectUri } from 'expo-auth-session';

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession(); // <-- will close web window after authentication

const useProxy = Platform.select({ web: false, default: true });

const client_id = 9999999999999;
const redirect_uri = "https://auth.expo.io/@your-expo-username/your-project-slug";
const scope = "user_profile,user_media";
const site = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=" + client_id + "&redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri + "&scope=" + scope + "&response_type=code&state=1";
  
const discovery = { authorizationEndpoint: site }

const GetInstagram = () => {


  const [request, response, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest({
    redirectUri: makeRedirectUri({
      useProxy,
      native: redirect_uri
    }),
    scopes: [scope],
    clientId: client_id
  }, discovery);


  useEffect(() => {
    if (response?.type === 'success') {
      const { code } = response.params; <--- the IG code will be returned here
      console.log("code : ", code);
    }
  }, [response]);



  return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => promptAsync({useProxy,windowFeatures: { width: 700, height: 600 }}) }>
          <Text>Connect Your Instagram</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
  )
}

export default GetInstagram;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is via using deeplink. I don't think it's the best practice though.

The response from the WebView will be sent to the redirect URL you've previously setup after successful authentication. Please set the redirect URL to your app. For example, on iOS if you have URL Scheme as "myapp123" then, anytime you open your browser and type myapp123://.. it will open your app and your app should be able to get response sent from the instagram.